# Why does GetComponent(TextMeshProUGUI).SetText only change the Text mesh component of the first Prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child

In my project I have a window that contains an input field. The script for the window then spawns a prefab named whatever I input. The script that I have running in the prefab that is instantiated has a function that should change the text mesh into this new name. However, when i run this script the name changes for the first instantiated prefab and all further prefabs have a the default name I typed into the text mesh component.

My prefab has a child canvas that contains the child text mesh pro UGUI

This is the Code I use for the window

```
public Toggle EnableSwitch;
public TMP_InputField inputField;

public GameObject Entity;
public GameObject Panel;

public string nameText;
public void OpenPanel()
{
    if(Panel != null)
    {
        bool isActive = Panel.activeSelf;

        Panel.SetActive(!isActive);

        if(isActive == true && EnableSwitch.isOn)
        {
            Produce();
        }
    }

}
public void NameAssign(string newName)
{
    nameText = newName;
}

public void Produce()
{
    float h = 2f * Camera.main.orthographicSize;
    float w = h * Camera.main.aspect;


    float x0 = 0 - w / 2;
    float y0 = 0 - h / 2;
    float x1 = x0 + w;
    float y1 = y0 + h;

    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(x0, x1), Random.Range(y0, y1), 0);


    print(nameText); //this is to make sure the name is being taken in
    Entity.name = nameText; //this is to assure the entity is renamed
    Instantiate(Entity, position, Quaternion.identity);
    Debug.Log(Entity.name); // this is a second check

}
```

This is the code that I run within my prefab

```
public Color fillColor = Color.blue;

public Slider radiusAdjuster;

private MeshFilter _meshFilter;
private LineRenderer _lineRenderer;
private CircleCollider2D _circleCollider2D;

public float radius;

public void Awake()
{
    _meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    _lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    _circleCollider2D = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
}
private void Update()
{
    Create();
    print(this.gameObject.name);
    GameObject.Find("Canvas/Test").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().SetText(this.gameObject.name);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

because [`GameObject.Find("Canvas/Test")`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) always returns the **same object**.

It goes through the entire Hierarchy top to bottom and returns the first encountered object matching the search pattern -> Unless you reorder htem later, this will always be the first prefab you spawned.

---

They even give you a hint in the API for `GameObject.Find`:

> Note: If you wish to find a child GameObject, it is often easier to use `Transform.Find`.

In your case it is not only easier but would be the only option since they will all have the same name in the Hierarchy. So if you rather want to `Find` an object below your own hierarchy you would want to use [`Transform.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) instead

```
transform.Find("Canvas/Test")
```

but you will have to provide the exact full valid path starting below that prefab object.

> Note: Find does not perform a recursive descend down a Transform hierarchy.

**Even better would actually be to simply referenced it via the Inspector and not use `Find` at all (see below)!**

---

And still: Do **NOT** use it in `Update` .. rather store the references **ONCE** at the beginning. Currently it doesn't seem like you would need to do it in `Update` at all actually.

```
// Best would actually be to reference this here via the Inspector
// by drag and drop and not get it on runtime AT ALL
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _testText;

private void Awake()
{
    // Only as fallback store it only ONCE
    if(!_testText)
    {
        _testText = transform.Find("Canvas/Test").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    }

    Create();
    // this.name equals gameObject.name btw ;)
    print(name);
    _testText.SetText(name);
}
```

then later re-use `_testText` wherever needed.

Comment: Changing the code to use transform.find worked great! Thank you